# Using range of values in column to summarize values in another column based on condition for first column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I cannot find any explanation about numpy.where function.

I have dataframe:

```
     activity     count    
0       1           25   
1       2           38   
2       3           49   
3       4           55                       
4       5           61   
5       6           74   
6       7           82  
7       8           98   
8       9           103   
9       10          4084
```

and I want to count values:

1. for rows where activity < 6, sum count (so for index < 5)
2. for rows where activity =< 6, sum count ( so for index =< 5)

and crate a charts for this two condition which shows sum count values.
I have tried:

```py
under_total = df[df.activity < 6]
under_total.loc['under_total'] = under_total.sum(axis = 0)
```

OR

```py
df['below_expectations'] = np.where(df['actibity'] < 6, df['activity'], df['hoursActive'])
```

But it seems I dont get it somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute a group for [`GroupBy.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) to feed it to [`plot.bar`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
(df.groupby(df['activity'].lt(6)
            .map({True: '<6', False: '≥6'}))
 ['count'].sum().plot.bar()
)
```

or with [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html), which gives you the advantage to have as many categories as you want:

```
(df.groupby(pd.cut(df['activity'], bins=[0,6,float('inf')],
                   labels=['<6', '≥6'], right=False))
 ['count'].sum().plot.bar()
)
```

output:

[image]

intermediate data:

```
(df.groupby(df['activity'].lt(6)
            .map({True: '<6', False: '≥6'}))
 ['count'].sum()
)
```

output:

```
activity
<6     228
≥6    4441
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for new column by `np.where` and then aggregate `sum`:

```
s = (df.assign(cat = np.where(df['activity'] < 6, 'less 6', 'higher 6'))
       .groupby('cat')['count']
       .sum())
print (s)
cat
higher 6    4441
less 6       228
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

and then plot by [`Series.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.bar.html):

```
s.plot.bar()
```

[image: img]